# SQL query to return 1 through int variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

in SQL Server, if I have an int variable, how can I write a query that returns the values 1 through the int variable's value?

So given:

```
declare @cnt int
set @cnt = 5
```

What query would return 1 - 5?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative answer to the others already given, maybe not so practical but it may be faster in certain situations.

If you have a known upper bound for the values of @cnt you will encounter (say 1000) you could create a simple one-column table with the first 1000 integers in it, like

```
val
---
1
2
3
4
...
```

and then whenever you want a set of integers you could get it using

```
select val
from integerTable
where val <= @cnt
```

Comment: Sounds crazy but tables of numbers save looping a lot of the time which is often more efficient.

Comment: This is the winner.  The data i'm running through has millions of rows, and I need to do this type of operation per row.  This is a very good solution

Answer (score 4):

You could do a **WHILE** loop in SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @Cnt int, 
        @Val int;
SET @Cnt = 5;
SET @Val = 0;

DECLARE @MyValues TABLE
(
  val int
);

WHILE @Val < @Cnt
 BEGIN
  SET @Val = @Val + 1;
  INSERT @MyValues(val)
  SELECT @Val;
 END;
SELECT Val FROM @MyValues;
```

Comment: Yea, I was hoping not to do any kind or cursor based processing (row cursor or while loop).  I was hoping for a set based execution solution.

Comment: perhaps you could wrap in in a function, would make it easier to use

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one query using a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), but you need to be aware of the MAXRECURSION query hint if your @cnt starts at a very high value.

```
DECLARE @cnt int;
SET @cnt = 5;

WITH Numbers AS (
    SELECT @cnt [Value]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Value] - 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE [Value] > 1
)
SELECT * FROM Numbers
ORDER BY [Value]
```

Having said that, though, doing it with a simple WHILE loop would be simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Great answer. I knew somebody would think recursion. (Don't forget the ';' before 'WITH'.)

Comment: Yeah - I always forget to add a semicolon after the command immediately before the WITH. I'll add the OP's variable declaration to be very explicit.

Comment: By default, this stops working around @cnt=100, as the maximum recursion limit is exhausted.

Comment: Which is why I specifically mentioned the MAXRECURSION query hint. Using it you can go up to 32767.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement an "output" value just using at the end of your query a SELECT statment...

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... Bla Bla, yadah, yadah;
SELECT (1 - @cnt);
```

and you will have the output that you want.

Comment: I dont think he meant '1 minus @cnt', he meant 'all the integers from 1 to @cnt in a table'

Comment: ohhh... I didn't got that part! I really thought it was 'minus' cause programaticaly 1 to 5 you write [1 ... 5] :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to do that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Sequence] (@start int, @end int, @step int)  
RETURNS @result table (num int) AS  
BEGIN 
    declare @num int
    set @num = @start

    while @num <= @end
        begin
        insert into @result (num) values (@num)
        set @num = @num + @step
        end
    return
END
```

With the function, you can select sequences like:

```
select * from dbo.Sequence(1,5,1)
```

This returns 1,2,3,4,5.

```
select * from dbo.Sequence(2,6,2)
```

Will return 2,4,6.  And so on :)

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum value of @cnt in your context is relatively low, you could populate a temporary or persistent table of integers and select from or join to it.

```
CREATE TABLE LotsOfNumbers(Number int not null)
INSERT INTO LotsOfNumbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO LotsOfNumbers VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO LotsOfNumbers VALUES(3)
...
INSERT INTO LotsOfNumbers VALUES(99)
INSERT INTO LotsOfNumbers VALUES(100)


DECLARE @cnt INT
SET @cnt = 30

SELECT *
FROM LotsOfNumbers
WHERE Number <= @cnt
ORDER BY Number
```

Of course, the time/space performance of this is going to depend on your situation, so I'd watch SQL Profiler to get an idea of the hit on the DB for each of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @cnt int
    set @cnt = 0
    while @cnt < 5
    begin
      set @cnt = @cnt + 1
      print 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know whether you wanted just one resultset (as per [José Basilio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832044/sql-query-to-return-1-through-int-variable/832072#832072)) or were happy with more than one

```
DECLARE @ctr INT
DECLARE @start INT

SET @ctr = 5
SET @start = 1

WHILE @start <= @ctr
BEGIN
   SELECT @start
   SET @start = @start + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating a table of a single columns with numbers is easy.

```
Create Table Numbers(Number INT);

INSERT INTO Numbers(Number) values(0);
INSERT INTO Numbers(Number) values(1);
INSERT INTO Numbers(Number) values(2);
.
.
INSERT INTO Numbers(Number) values(9);

-- To generate a list of 100000

SELECT * INTO TEST
FROM
(SELECT N1.Number * 1000 +  N2.Number * 100 + N3.Number * 10 + N4.Number * 1 as Num
FROM   Numbers N1
CROSS JOIN Numbers N2
CROSS JOIN Numbers N3
CROSS JOIN Numbers N4) AS N
ORDER BY Num;

--Then, You can use the above table for getting the numbers
SELECT * from TEST WHERE Num <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this years ago, so I figured out the fastest/simplest way if your database has a table with more records than you need to count.

First off, Despite suggestions you don't need to "create" a table of records... all you need is "ANY" table that already has records. As long as the table has more records than you need to count then you are good.

```
SELECT top (5) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by [Primary_Key] desc) AS Integer 
FROM SOME_TABLE   --that has more than 5 rows.
```

ALSO this is the elegant (math) way. Where you don't have a large table already in the database.

Use Split recursion, this allows you to generate a table with up to 2^n-1 integers where n is your recursion limit. Plus this is fully parameterized, so it can easily be put in a function

```
DECLARE @n int, @cnt int;
set @cnt = 5;
SET @n = LOG(@cnt)/LOG(2) +1; --use change of base to find LOG base 2

WITH Num AS (
    SELECT @n [Value]
    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Value] - 1
    FROM Num
    WHERE [Value] > 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Value] - 1
    FROM Num
    WHERE [Value] > 1
) 

SELECT * from (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Value asc) AS [Integer]
FROM Num
)i 
where [Integer] <= @cnt
```

The one downside to this is that it can generate up to twice as many records as needed during recursion, so it has the potential for more overhead than inline recursion. BUT completely avoids the recursion limit because of that. (you shouldn't ever have a need to list the first 2^100-1 integers.) (also I'm just going to predict you don't have a computer with that much hard drive space.)

This downside is why I created the next function. Which uses the same doubling technique as split recursion but inside a while loop. AND the last time it runs it only puts the necessary records not double. This function also allows you to specify a range and returns all the numbers in that range with a 0 based index of those numbers. I used to consider that zero base column as a useless artifact of the computation but it has come in extremely helpfull to have both the range and its index in one line.

```
create   function [dbo].[fn_Integers] 
(
@Min_Integer  int = 1
,@Max_Integer int 
)
RETURNS @retTable TABLE 
    ([BASE]  int identity(0,1)
    ,[INTEGER] int) 
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @RANGE int
    SET @RANGE = @Max_Integer-@Min_Integer

    insert into @retTable
    select NULL --initial value for recursion

    While ((SELECT MAX([BASE]) FROM @retTable r) < @RANGE )
    BEGIN
        INSERT into @retTable
        select [INTEGER] from @retTable r
        where [BASE] < (SELECT @RANGE - MAX([BASE])  FROM @retTable r)
    END

    Update @retTable set
    [INTEGER] = [BASE] + @Min_Integer

RETURN
END
GO
```

it can do about 50000 integers per second (on my workstation) 
and output looks like

```
SELECT * FROM [fn_Integers](18,50000)

BASE    INTEGER
-----------------
0       18
1       19
2       20
...
49982   50000
```